# OpenGL Frambuffers, Rendering to Depth Texture

Tags: c++, opengl, shader

**The problem:**

The code is supposed to render the scene and write the results into a depth texture. When I check the contents of the texture after the render, it contains all 0 values.

**What I have tried:**

I have tried outputting to the screen instead of the texture and it draws the scene as expected, so the vertex and matrix values are being read correctly. I have tried multiple tutorials an they all basically say to bind a framebuffer to a texture, which is exactly what I do. I believe the trouble is probably some sort of versioning issue or something I overlooked like a parameter or something. I've been at it for a few hours and I can't quite spot it. Hopefully someone can.

**Details:**

- OpenGL 3.1
- GLSL 140

*Note: The purpose of this is to allow shadow mapping to work. So there are 2 sets of shaders and draw functions. One to draw to the depth buffer and the other to draw the objects.*

**Code:**

*Shader initialization code:*

```
void Engine::loadMObject()
{
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &MObject::fbo);
    glGenTextures(1, &MObject::shadowMap);

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, MObject::fbo);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, MObject::shadowMap);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, windowWidth, windowHeight, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);

    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, MObject::shadowMap, 0);

    glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE);
    glReadBuffer(GL_NONE);

    GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
    assi(status == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE, "FBO error!");

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

    MObject::shadowProgram = Shader::compile((char*)MObject::shadowVertexShaderFile, (char*)MObject::shadowFramentShaderFile);

    MObject::shadowPositionLoc = glGetAttribLocation(MObject::shadowProgram, "position");

    MObject::shadowModelProjectionMatrixLoc = glGetUniformLocation(MObject::shadowProgram, "modelProjectionMatrix");

    MObject::objectProgram = Shader::compile((char*)MObject::objectVertexShaderFile, (char*)MObject::objectFragmentShaderFile);

    MObject::objectPositionLoc = glGetAttribLocation(MObject::objectProgram, "position");
    MObject::objectTexCoordLoc = glGetAttribLocation(MObject::objectProgram, "texCoord");
    MObject::objectNormalLoc = glGetAttribLocation(MObject::objectProgram, "normal");

    MObject::objectWorldMatrixLoc = glGetUniformLocation(MObject::objectProgram, "worldMatrix");
    MObject::objectViewMatrixLoc = glGetUniformLocation(MObject::objectProgram, "viewMatrix");
    MObject::objectProjectionMatrixLoc = glGetUniformLocation(MObject::objectProgram, "projectionMatrix");
    MObject::objectTextureLoc = glGetUniformLocation(MObject::objectProgram, "texture");
    MObject::objectDepthModelProjectionMatrixLoc = glGetUniformLocation(MObject::objectProgram, "depthModelProjectionMatrix");

}
```

*Object initialization code*

```
void Engine::load(MObject* object)
{
    unload(object);

    // |Physics|
    object->mesh = memoryManager.alloc<btTriangleIndexVertexArray>(
                                        object->elements.length()/3,
                                        (int*)&object->elements[0],
                                        3*sizeof(GLuint),
                                        object->attributes.length(),
                                        (btScalar*)&object->attributes[0],
                                        sizeof(MObject::Attribute));

    btCollisionShape* shape;
    btScalar mass = 0;
    btVector3 inertia(0, 0, 0);
    if(object->dynamic)
    {
        shape = memoryManager.alloc<btGImpactMeshShape>(object->mesh);
        ((btGImpactMeshShape*)shape)->updateBound();
        mass = 1;
        shape->calculateLocalInertia(mass, inertia);
    }else{
        shape = memoryManager.alloc<btBvhTriangleMeshShape>(object->mesh, true);
    }

    object->rigidBody = (btRigidBody*)memoryManager.galloc(sizeof(btRigidBody), memoryManager.alignment<btRigidBody>());
    new (object->rigidBody) btRigidBody(mass, object, shape, inertia); // 16-byte aligned param work around...
    physicsWorld->addRigidBody(object->rigidBody);

    // |Graphics|

    // Vertex array object

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &object->objectvao);
    glBindVertexArray(object->objectvao);

    // Vertex buffer object

    glGenBuffers(1, &object->vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, object->vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, object->attributes.length()*sizeof(MObject::Attribute), object->attributes.data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Vertex attributes

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(object->objectPositionLoc);
    glVertexAttribPointer(object->objectPositionLoc, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(MObject::Attribute), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(object->objectTexCoordLoc);
    glVertexAttribPointer(object->objectTexCoordLoc, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(MObject::Attribute), (void*)offsetof(class MObject::Attribute, texCoord));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(object->objectNormalLoc);
    glVertexAttribPointer(object->objectNormalLoc, 3, GL_SHORT, GL_TRUE, sizeof(MObject::Attribute), (void*)offsetof(class MObject::Attribute, normal));

    // Element buffer object

    object->eboNumElements = object->elements.length();
    glGenBuffers(1, &object->ebo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, object->ebo);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, object->elements.length()*sizeof(GLuint), object->elements.data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindVertexArray(0);

    // Shadow vao

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &object->shadowvao);
    glBindVertexArray(object->shadowvao);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, object->vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, object->ebo);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(object->shadowPositionLoc);
    glVertexAttribPointer(object->shadowPositionLoc, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(MObject::Attribute), (void*)0);

    glBindVertexArray(0);


    mObjectList.pushBack(object);
}
```

*Draw code:*

/* START - SECTION OF MAIN UPDATE LOOP */
    // |Draw update|

```
// Shadow Pass

// testing...
if(isKeyDown(SDL_SCANCODE_0)){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glUseProgram(MObject::shadowProgram);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, MObject::fbo);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, MObject::shadowMap);
    for(U32 i=0;i<mObjectList.length();++i)
    {
        drawShadow(mObjectList[i]);
    }
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, MObject::shadowMap);
    GLfloat* pixels = new GLfloat[windowWidth*windowHeight];
    glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, pixels);
    for(U32 i=0;i<windowHeight*windowHeight;++i)
    {
        if(pixels[i] != 0.0f)
            printd("I GOT IT!");
    }
    delete[] pixels;
}else{


    // Object Pass
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glUseProgram(MObject::objectProgram);
    for(U32 i=0;i<mObjectList.length();++i)
    {
        drawObject(mObjectList[i]);
    }
}


// Swapping buffers
SDL_GL_SwapWindow(mainWindow);
```

/* END - SECTION OF MAIN UPDATE LOOP*/

```
void Engine::drawObject(MObject* object)
{
    TransformMatrix matrix;
    getOrthographicMatrix(matrix, -10, 10, 10, -10, -10, 20);
    glBindVertexArray(object->objectvao);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(MObject::objectWorldMatrixLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, (GLfloat*)&object->worldMatrix);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(MObject::objectViewMatrixLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, (GLfloat*)&getViewMatrix());
    glUniformMatrix4fv(MObject::objectProjectionMatrixLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, (GLfloat*)&getProjectionMatrix());

    glUniformMatrix4fv(MObject::objectDepthModelProjectionMatrixLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, (GLfloat*)&getProjectionMatrix());
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, object->tbo);
    glUniform1i(MObject::objectTextureLoc, 0);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, object->eboNumElements, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
}

void Engine::drawShadow(MObject* object)
{
    TransformMatrix matrix;
    //getOrthographicMatrix(matrix, -10, 10, 10, -10, -10, 20);
    matrix = getProjectionMatrix() * getViewMatrix() * object->worldMatrix;
    glBindVertexArray(object->shadowvao);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(MObject::shadowModelProjectionMatrixLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, (GLfloat*)&matrix);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, object->eboNumElements, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

}
```

*Vertex Shader:*

```
#version 140

in vec3 position;

uniform mat4 modelProjectionMatrix;

void main(){
    gl_Position =  modelProjectionMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0f);
}
```

*Fragment Shader:*

```
#version 140

out float fragmentdepth;

void main(){
    fragmentdepth = gl_FragCoord.z;
}
/*
out vec4 color;

void main(){
    color = vec4(clamp(gl_FragCoord.z, 0.0f, 1.0f), 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}*/
```

Comment: did you try adding `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);`

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out. Apparently if you rearrange the opengl calls a little bit it works. I believe what I did was put glBindFramebuffer before glUseProgram and it worked.